# SVN Defining the Root Directory

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I have installed subversion on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I have created a repository under `/home/svnadmin/svn/repo-one`.  I can then use ToroiseSVN to connect and view by using the full path - `/home/svnadmin/svn/repo-one`.

I would like to make it so that `/home/svnadmin/svn` is the root directory for `svnserve` to use.  I have consulted the `svnserve --help` manual and found this:

```
-r [--root] ARG: root of directory to serve
```

But when I attempt to run the command:

```
svnserve -r /home/svnadmin/svn/
```

When I execute that command I get the error:

```
You must specify exactly one of -d, -i, -t or -X.
```

Can anyone help me please?  Have I misunderstood what the `-r` command is supposed to do?  I've tried searching for the answer and can't find a solution to my problem anywhere.

Comment: They control how you want the process to run: as a daemon, as a back-end to the xinetd daemon, tunnel mode (don't know) or debug mode. How do you want to set this up permanently? [Documentation here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking).

Comment: As a back-end to the xinted daemon.

Comment: Then you want `-i`. [Sample xinetd config here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking.inetd).

Comment: Thanks @Rup - that's the ticket.  If you post this as the answer I will make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These flags select which model the process uses to listen for connections:

- `-d` - run as a standalone daemon, listening on a port itself
- `-i` - run as an xinetd backend, communicating with a parent process on stdin and stdout
- `-t` - in SSH tunnel mode
- `-X` - in debug listen mode, accepting a single connection then stopping.

[Documentation here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking). So you do need to select one: from discussion in the comments it sounds like you want `-i` for xinetd mode, and there's a sample xinetd configuration for this in the documentation too:

```
svn stream tcp nowait svnadmin /usr/bin/svnserve svnserve -i -r /home/svnadmin/svn/
```

assuming you have `svn 3690/tcp` in /etc/services to define the port, which you almost certainly do on a modern distro.

Comment: Thanks @Rup!  I didn't want to take credit for your help!